# How to identify domain which ddos

Tags: cloudflare, ddos

I have several domain alisases for my site.
For example: domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com.

All domains has NS servers provided by Cloudflare.

*How I can identify domains in the aliases list which ddosing?*

Comment: What kind of web server are you using, cant you just check the access logs and check if a certain IP address keeps popping up?

Answer (score 0):

Your server logs should be able to tell you which site you're having an issue with.